# SQL Question on New entries after a given date

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Question: SQL query to best get the desired result below.

Input:

| Identifier | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1234 | 2022-08-11 |
| 7890 | 2022-08-11 |
| 4444 | 2022-08-13 |

Output:

| Identifier | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 7890 | 2022-08-11 |
| 4444 | 2022-08-13 |

Note:
Want only new entries that was not in the past. Tried doing a self left join with the same table with a.Identifier = b.Identifier and a.date < b.date but it gives me 1234 entry that I do not need.

My Query (Yielding extra entry of 1234)

```
select * from
Table a left join Table b
on a.Identifier = b.Identifier
and a.Date < b.Date
where b.Identifier is null
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please share your code/query.

Comment: Is this a MySQL problem, or a Snowflake problem? What did you try to resolve it?

Comment: Hi Sorry, I am a new user. I am just looking for a SQL that's compatible with both MySQL and Snowflake. Could you please not close this but advise how I can fix the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Using aggregation we can try:

```sql
SELECT Identifier, MAX(Date) AS Date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Identifier
HAVING MIN(Date) = MAX(Date);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But, I don't want to hardcode a date in the query. As more entry gets added I want it to look for older dates and pick the new entry

Comment: This does not seem to work. I still get the 1234 entry which I shouldn't.

Comment: I have edited again.  Aggregation may be the simplest option here.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table_name 
where 
  identifier >= '4444'
```

if you using double table maybe you can use

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table_name_a 
  inner join table_name_b on table_name_a.id = table_name_b.id 
where 
  identifier >= '4444'
```

i hope i can help you

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Using `QUALIFY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
-- WHERE ...
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Identifier) = 1;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way you phrased the question made your problem sound more complicated than it actually is. If you just need to filter for identifiers that don't repeat in the table, all you need to do is get the counts and limit it to 1. Lukasz's answers achieves the same using `qualify`

```
select *
from table_name
where identifer in (select identifier from table_name group by identifier having count(*)=1)
```